# Identifier "i" undefined

Tags: c, msp432

Hello I am using an MSP432 with CCS IDE, I am trying to use an array that points to the next integer in int x[i] ={} for a systick timer to increment the 16x2 lcd position while checking for if statements to execute. I keep getting (Identifier "i" undefined) error on the line mentioned in the code sample when I declare int x[i] = {}; What would be the proper way of declaring it?

//This is my global initialization before main:

```
#include "msp.h"
#include "lcdLib.h" //lcd library
void GPIO(); //called in main
void init_systick(); //initializes systick
void Start_Game(); //function with all the if statements called in systick handler
void SysTick_Handler(); //calls Start_Game and increments i += 1;  
int x[i] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};// error here: Identifier "i" undefined
void delayMs(); //delay timer 
int Score = 0; //score marker
```

Comment: Not related to your question, functions of the form `void GPIO();` is using obsolescent style (since some ~25 years back). So it is always wrong, write `void GPIO (void);` instead of writing ancient, outdated C.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it really has nothing to do with EE. It's a pure C misunderstanding and as such belongs on StackOverflow. The fact that it's being done on an MSP43x is incidental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in C and C++, you **CAN'T** define the array size with a variable:

```
int i;
i = 31;
int x[i] = { /* fill with elements*/ } //invalid definition because size identifier is a variable
```

***NOTE:** From C99 it's possible. Thanks Lundin for clarification.*

Another way is to define `i` (or whatever) with a pre-processor directive

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 31
int x[ARRAY_SIZE] = { /* fill with elements */ };
```

What you can do is to define an array without size, then get the number of elements info and assign to a variable:

```
int i; //define first (read note below)
int x[] = { /* fill with elements */ }; //fill the array with items
i = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);
```

---

**NOTE:** Depending on the compiler and settings, you may not be asked to strictly define a variable before use. For example, the following code may not generate an error:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) //the `i` appears here first time
    //do something
```

Comment: "First, in C and C++, you CAN'T define the array size with a variable" Sure you can, in certain conditions. Either at local scope in case of C, which supports VLA, or as a constant in C++.

Comment: "you may not be asked to strictly define a variable before use" You have to do that in standard C, all the way back to the first C standard released 33 years ago.

Comment: @Lundin constant and variable are different things. So, for a fixed length array, you can't define the size with a *variable*, but you can with a *constant*. And, of course, variable-length arrays (a.k.a. dynamic arrays) allow you to define and, if necessary, re-define the size dynamically but they are out of scope here because the user is trying to deal with fixed-length arrays. That's why I didn't mention dynamic memory management (allocation, re-allocation, freeing).

Comment: Sure you can. Variable-length arrays and dynamically allocated arrays are two entirely separate things. In the year 1999, variable-length arrays were added to the C language. The C standard doesn't specify how they are allocated, though most commonly by far is stack allocation. They cannot be resized later. (Notably, neither VLA nor dynamic allocation are recommended practices in embedded systems.)

Comment: Btw you have a syntax error here: `i = sizeof(x[]) / sizeof(x[0])`.

Comment: @Lundin yeah, you're right on that. DAs can do everything that VLAs can, probably that's why I treated them as the same thing. And yes, I checked and from C99 VLAs have been added to standard. I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: @Lundin and for the variable declaration, yes C strictly requires proper variable declaration before use but some C++ compilers may figure out if one is used without declaration (like in the snippet I added to the end). CCS and its compiler support both C and C++ and we don't know which one the OP uses.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler error is self-explanatory. Get rid of `i`, there is no such variable. Should be
`int x[] = { ... };`

Answer (score 2):

You're defining an array x[] (don't need an i in there).
But you'll have to define the index i which is a variable on its if you want to use it in the code.

so:

```
int i; // or int i = 0; if you want to initialze it diectly.
int x[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0}
```